# Flagging question as duplicate when the original was migrated to another site

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39286/is-global-warming-a-natural-phenomena-afterall) was recently posted to our site.  Particularly, the question cites [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214242817300426#!) and is asking about the validity of the study.  Another question in the same format regarding the same paper was posted a few days previously, [and was then migrated to EarthScience](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12133/does-this-paper-using-neural-nets-prove-industrialization-is-irrelevant-to-glo).  How can we flag this question as a duplicate when the original was migrated to another StackExchange site?

Comment: Custom close reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. The Stack Exchange software does not allow to close questions as cross-site duplicates. The closest I've seen is migrating the question and then closing it as duplicate, but it would be low value and would mark the original question as "migration rejected" which is probably baffling and not what users expect.

My advice is: add a link to the duplicate in the comments and let the question stay if otherwise appropriate.